# Getting unexpected `Cannot set the value of read-only property` when writing own plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a DSL like the following:

```
toolSetups {
    someTool {
        argsFile = file('run/some_tool/xrun_files.f')
    }
    someOtherTool {
        argsFile = file('run/some_other_tool/xrun_files.f')
    }
}
```

I do this by adding an extension to the project, which is a container for `ToolSetup` entries:

```
extensions.add('toolSetups', project.container(ToolSetup))
```

I followed the examples in the user guide and declared the `argsFile` property in `ToolSetup`:

```
interface ToolSetup {
    Property<File> getArgsFile()
}
```

I searched around and found that this only works if `ToolSetup` has a `name` property. I reworked `ToolSetup` to be:

```
abstract class ToolSetup {
    private final String name
    
    public ToolSetup(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    String getName() {
        return name
    }

    abstract Property<File> getArgsFile()
}
```

I'm getting the following:

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'argsFile' for object of type ToolSetup$Inject.

I also tried explicitly calling `argsFile.set(file(...))`, but this gives me the same error. I also tried to explicitly create `Property` instances using `ObjectFactory`, but still got the same.

I already wrote a plugin that does something similar, where it works, but that plugin is written in Java. I'm guessing there's some trivial mistake here related to Groovy and letting Gradle manage the implementation for me, which I'm not seeing. I'd be very grateful if someone could point it out.

---

Here's the entire `build.gradle` file that reproduces this issue:

```
abstract class ToolSetup {
    private final String name
    
    public ToolSetup(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    String getName() {
        return name
    }

    abstract Property<File> getArgsFile()
}

extensions.add('toolSetups', project.container(ToolSetup))

toolSetups {
    someTool {
        argsFile = file('run/some_tool/xrun_files.f')
    }
    someOtherTool {
        argsFile = file('run/some_other_tool/xrun_files.f')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to  get the below to work

buildSrc/src/main/java/com/sample/Resource.java

```
package com.sample;
import org.gradle.api.provider.Property;
import java.net.URI;

public interface Resource {
    // Type must have a read-only 'name' property
    String getName();

    Property<URI> getUri();

    Property<String> getUserName();

}
```

build.gradle

```
extensions.add("download", project.objects.domainObjectContainer(com.sample.Resource.class))

download {
    register('t1') {
        uri = uri("http://abc")
        userName = "t1u"
    }
    register('t2') {
        uri = uri("https://abc")
        userName = "t2u"
    }
}

println "download info "
download.each { println String.format("{name: %s, uri: '%s', userName: %s", it.getName(), it.getUri().getOrNull(), it.getUserName().getOrNull()) }
```

the output produces

```
> Configure project :
download info 
{name: t1, uri: 'http://abc', userName: t1u
{name: t2, uri: 'https://abc', userName: t2u

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
3 actionable tasks: 3 up-to-date
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in Gradle. Under certain conditions, the injected implementation doesn't support the `=`, while in others it does. My code was using `project.container()` to create the object, which is busted, while your code is using `project.objects.domainObjectContainer()`, which works.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in Gradle w.r.t. the injected implementation for the `toolSetups` container: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/23525

Using `project.objects.domainObjectContainer()` to create the container, instead of `project.container()` works.

To define the extension, we have to do:

```
extensions.add('toolSetups', objects.domainObjectContainer(ToolSetup))
```

---

Note, it's not necessary to give Gradle an abstract class for `ToolSetup`. It can also be supplied an interface, as long as that interface contains a `name` property. It will be able to inject a constructor by itself. The following is sufficient:

```
interface ToolSetup {
    String getName()
    Property<File> getArgsFile()
}
```

Alternatively, it's also possible to extend the `Named` interface:

```
interface ToolSetup extends Named {
    Property<File> getArgsFile()
}
```